# Change CSS for logged in users

Tags: functions, jquery, css

In my css i have a hidden `div id`:

```
#example {display:none;}
```

How can I set this to `display:block` for logged in users only?

I am assuming using Jquery would be the best option here for best performance? Or is it better to use a function in functions.php ?

Comment: Where and how are you defining your CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `body_class()`:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

If you use the function `body_class()` you can set on your css like this:

```
.example {
    display: none;
}
.logged-in .example {
    display: block
}
```

Comment: awesome - had no idea about this class :) thank you guys xx

Comment: Joanna Mikalai you're welcome. @ChipBennett =D

Comment: I have a problem using this technique: I have setup a menu item (custom link) with class `logout`  and the following CSS 

`#toolbar .logout a{
  display:none;
}

#toolbar .logged-in .logout a{
  display:inline;
}`

But when logged-in, the link is invisible. `body_class()` is being used because when user is logged-in in can see in the source of the page the class `.logged-in` is being injected in the code. Here's the link: http://me-about.me/test/

Comment: Hello @Riccardo you could use `.toolbar .logout { display: none } .logged-in .toolbar .logout { display: inline }`